# Is .Net Integration of Credit Cards with PayPal Advanced Checkout Possible?

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have an ASP.Net website, and am attempting to re-implement our existing PayPal checkout flow (previously based on their Payments Pro product/SOAP APIs) to behave similarly under their Advanced Checkout flow with REST APIs. (PayPal is deprecating fraud filters in Payments Pro and it's forcing the change from a business perspective).

I've reviewed the PayPal v2 REST APIs. PayPal-based checkout is fine (and I have a working flow for it) but can find no means to directly accept credit cards for processing. The closest I've come is to use the PayPal.Net library and attempt to run the card as a FundingInstrument -- but this returns an "PAYEE_ACCOUNT_INVALID" in the Sandbox, even though that account Advanced Credit and Debit box checked in the app settings. I *could* simply direct all payments to the PayPal main page and let the user choose the funding source from there, but the user experience of doing a Visa payment this way is cumbersome and likely to lead to cart abandonment for users accustomed to simply running their stored Visa card as a method of payment.

The available JavaScript code I've seen appears to render the credit card buttons on the site by calling host code, and effectively executing the transaction entirely on PayPal's servers. If my own Javascript was better, I might be able to figure out the loop of how to stuff in the user's saved details into the rendered buttons, but I'd much prefer some sort of .Net-based solution. Has anyone had any experience building such a thing? Is it even possible in the current REST API?

Any pointers would be much appreciated--never had so much trouble locating sample code or resources for a project, and am starting to wonder if it's simply not supported...

Thanks,
-Pete

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use [Advanced Credit and Debit Card hosted fields](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/). The CSS of these fields can be customized to match the rest of your site, but  the actual number, cvv, expiry date fields are hosted directly by PayPal (in tiny iframes), which frees you from having to do a PCI SAQ-D assessment for that processing.

This does not give a solution cards you've already stored numbers for, however. You could vault all those cards, using the PayPal vault API and then later referencing each vaulted payment token to create orders with them. This way you'll be able to eliminate the storage of actual card information on your systems.

Comment: Is there a REST API call you can point me to that would allow me to interface it from ASP.net? I don't see a linkage from the Orders API (or is there some behind the scenes magic that looks for their credit card fields on the form?). .Net sample code would be amazing, if available.

Comment: I haven't worked with it myself so all I can suggest is starting with https://www.google.com/search?q=%22asp.net%22+paypal+rest and finding sample code that interfaces with the Orders API in general, and adapting it to work as an ACDC integration